# Assign rank to items of an array which is already sorted  

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
[1303] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Al****
    [Total] => 479896.025
)
[13047] => Array
(
    [Name]  => An****
    [Total] => 1999.871
)
[13065] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Ao****
    [Total] => 3947.761
)
[13054] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Ba****
    [Total] => 15666.826
)
[13020] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Bb****
    [Total] => 22366.6456
)
[13016] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Be****
    [Total] => 8307.389
)
```

The array is sorted by name. I need to assign rank to each array item based on total. In the above example, item 1303 should have the rank 1, item 13020 should have a rank of 2 and so on; the array must maintain its existing sorting. What is the simplest way to do this. Expected output:

```
[1303] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Al****
    [Total] => 479896.025
    [Rank]  => 1
)
[13047] => Array
(
    [Name]  => An****
    [Total] => 1999.871
    [Rank]  => 6
)
[13065] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Ao****
    [Total] => 3947.761
    [Rank]  => 5
)
[13054] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Ba****
    [Total] => 15666.826
    [Rank]  => 3
)
[13020] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Bb****
    [Total] => 22366.6456
    [Rank]  => 2
)
[13016] => Array
(
    [Name]  => Be****
    [Total] => 8307.389
    [Rank]  => 4
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the array using the Total value:

```
function totalSort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Total'] > $b['Total']) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['Total'] < $b['Total']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

uasort($array, 'totalSort');
```

Add the Rank elements:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as &$element) {
    $element['Rank'] = $i++;
}
```

Sort the array by Name again (if required):

```
function nameSort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Name'] > $b['Name']) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['Name'] < $b['Name']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

uasort($array, 'nameSort');
```

Comment: Works just fine. Note that I rewrote totalSort function in one line: `return $b['Total'] - $a['Total']` (descending); likewise for nameSort: `return strcmp($a["Name"], $b["Name"])` (ascending).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this...

1. Clone the array
2. Sort the clone by total (msort?)
3. Loop through the original
4. Search the sorted array by original name (in loop)
5. Get index of search, and set as ranking in original

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do the two steps:

#### Sort array

Carefully chose one [sort function](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) that best fits your needs for this. I guess [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) would do:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if( $a['Total'] == $b['Total']){
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Total'] < $b['Total']) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort( $array, 'cmp');
```

#### Assign rank

Probably `foreach` loop would be easiest way to do this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach( $array as &$item){
    $item['Rank'] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```